# Send checked unchecked checkbox value with array name

Tags: php, html

In my project I have to use checkbox with an array name like

```
<input name="current[]" type="hidden" value="No">
<input class="current_checkbox" name="current[]" type="checkbox" value="Yes">
```

But when post request is sending, It sends 2 array current[]=no and current[]=yes both when checkbox is checked and send current[]=no only when checkbox is not checked. So, the problem is Ex.overall array length is 3 then if a single checkbox is checked from all, Its length is 4. IF two checkboxe are checked then checkbox array length is 5. how can I overcome this problem and how to send current[]=no only when checkbox is not checked and send current[]=yes only when checked.

Ex:here i have 3 array but getting 4 checkbox value with yes and no both value.

[image]

Comment: change your hidden variable name

Comment: Then how can i send value for unchecked checkbox.

Comment: why are you using same name for input type hidden and checkbox

Comment: You can directly check the values of checkbox with print_r($_POST['current']) function

Comment: used jquery will be more easy to handle